# Deleting a target folder in many subfolders with python

Tags: python, shell, directory, operating-system

i have a folder X with many (over 500) subfolders in it. In those subfolders there is sometimes a subfolder TARGET that i want to delete. I was considering using a script for doing this.

i am not python expert but i tried to make this script, before using it risking to lose files i'd need, can you please check if it is correct?? thanks

```
import os
import shutil
dir = '/Volume/X'
targetDir = 'myDir'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    dirpath = subdir
    if dirpath.exists() and dirpath.is_dir():
    shutil.rmtree(dirpath)
```

Comment: if you want to test it you should create a test folder similar to the other folder and run your script on that before running on the actual folder.

Comment: In a shell: `find X -depth -type d -name TARGET -exec rm -rf \{\} \;`

Comment: oh didn't know i could do with shell commands too :) it's super interesting thanks @Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, I fixed your code and made it a bit more useful so anyone can use it :) enjoy

```
#coded by antoclk @ antonioaunix@gmail.com
import os
import shutil

#in dir variable you should put the path you need to scan
dir = '/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/main' 
#in target variable you should put the exact name of the folder you want to delete. Be careful to use it, it will delete all the files and subfolders contained in the target dir.
target = 'x'

os.system('cls') 
os.system('clear')

print('Removing '+target+' folder from '+dir+' and all its subfolders.')

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir):
    for item in dirnames:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, item)
        #print(os.path.join(dirpath, item))
        if item == 'target':
            print('deleting '+fullPath)
            shutil.rmtree(fullPath)

print('Task completed!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a slight bug in the accepted answer (by [antoaunix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17211120/antoaunix)) at the level of `if item == 'target'`. It had to be `if item == target` and also restructured the code a little bit.

```py
import shutil
import os


class FolderCleaner:
    @staticmethod
    def _init(target: str, dirname: str) -> None:
        print(f"Removing '{target}' from '{dirname}' and all it's sub-folders")

    @staticmethod
    def _reset_view() -> None:
        os.system("cls")
        os.system("clear")
    
    @staticmethod
    def delete_all_folders(dirname: str, folder_name: str) -> None:
        FolderCleaner._reset_view()
        FolderCleaner._init(target=folder_name, dirname=dirname)
        for dir_path, dir_names, filenames in os.walk(dirname):
            for item in dir_names:
                full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, item)
                if item == folder_name:
                    print(f"deleting {full_path}")
                    shutil.rmtree(full_path)
        print("Task completed!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    FolderCleaner.delete_all_folders(dirname="./", folder_name="__pycache__")
```